# Ionic 3 Platform Ready fires only after app closes or is suspended

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic-native

I have an ionic 3 app using geolocation. The app works fine on Android but I have a weird behaviour on IOS. When I run the app on IOS its starts normal but does not ask for location permission until I suspend or close the app thus causing the app not to be fully functional. My geolocation id wrapped in platform.ready function in my component constructor:

```
 platform.ready().then(() => {
      geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(position => {
        this.current_postion_lat = position.coords.latitude;
        this.current_postion_long = position.coords.longitude;
        console.log('Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '\n' +
          'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude + '\n' +
          'Altitude: ' + position.coords.altitude + '\n' +
          'Accuracy: ' + position.coords.accuracy + '\n' +
          'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy + '\n' +
          'Heading: ' + position.coords.heading + '\n' +
          'Speed: ' + position.coords.speed + '\n' +
          'Timestamp: ' + position.timestamp + '\n');

        console.log("Got to Location Provider Constructor");
        const watch = geolocation.watchPosition().subscribe(pos => {
          this.current_postion_lat = pos.coords.latitude;
          this.current_postion_long = pos.coords.longitude;
          console.log('lat: ' + pos.coords.latitude + ', lon: ' + pos.coords.longitude);
        });

      });
    });
```

My ionic info:

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.3
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.1

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4
Cordova Platforms  : android 8.0.0 browser 5.0.4 ios 5.1.1
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.1
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
ios-sim           : 8.0.2 
Node              : v10.16.3
npm               : 4.1.2 
OS                : macOS
Xcode             : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

Please help. This has prevented me from releasing.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS you have to add the below configuration to your configuration.xml file.

```
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
   <string>We use your location for full functionality of certain app features.</string>
</edit-config>
```

Comment: I tried that earlier. Does not solve the issue. Still have to close or suspend app for platform.ready to fire. The popup for permission popup as desired, just not on initial install